# Magento 2 move same element to multiple location

Tags: magento2

I am trying to move the "product.info.social" element to both "product.info.addtocart" and "product.info.addtocart.additional" in the "catalog_product_view.xml" as

```
<move element="product.info.social" destination="product.info.addtocart.additional" />
    <move element="product.info.social" destination="product.info.addtocart" />
```

But it is moving only to the "product.info.addtocart" block. How could I move the "product.info.social" to both blocks?

Comment: Create new product.info.social block as a separate name and then move

Comment: Logically you are trying to move the social block to one and then another location then it will show only in add to cart its right.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Please share, if you find any solution.